# Как в Viber bot отменить показ сообщения в чате?

Tags: viber, viber-api

Отправляю json:

```
[{
    "Columns": 2,
    "Rows": 2,
    "ActionType": "reply",
    "ActionBody": "salmon",
    "BgColor": "#e0e0e0",
    "Silent": "true",
    "Image": "https:\/\/podrobnosti.ua\/media\/pictures\/2019\/4\/14\/thumbs\/740x415\/foto-znaki-zodiaka_rect_378006f563bb5d79bb902a0d8a5fdea6.jpg"
}, {
    "Columns": 2,
    "Rows": 2,
    "ActionType": "reply",
    "ActionBody": "salmon",
    "BgColor": "#e0e0e0",
    "Silent": "true",
    "Image": "https:\/\/github.com\/apple-touch-icon.png"
}, {
    "Columns": 2,
    "Rows": 2,
    "ActionType": "reply",
    "ActionBody": "salmon",
    "BgColor": "#e0e0e0",
    "Silent": "true",
    "Image": "https:\/\/github.com\/apple-touch-icon.png"
}]
```

По клику на кнопку, в чат приходит картинка.
Как сделать чтобы в чате ничего не отображалось.
В документации написано что надо отправлять "Silent", я отправляю, все равно отображается.
Что я делаю не так?
[Документация](https://developers.viber.com/docs/tools/keyboards/#buttons-parameters)

Comment: Не совсем понятен смысл отправки сообщений, которые не должны отображаться

Comment: Такой заказ. Аналог viber://pa?chatURI=burgitest . webhook то получает сообщение.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Нужно указывать версию API

```
'min_api_version' => 4
```